# How to access firebase database value in json format

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My JSON structure is as follows-:

```
[how can i access this json structure for firebase realtime db, basically i want to print 
    id(numeric num), then the email_id][1]


  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UslTG.png
```

I want to read the numeric value and email and that numeric value will going to change every time and i want to read the value latestly added inside article/.?

Comment: It looks like some details are missing in your question. Can you please fill them in? Do take a look at our guide for tips on asking good questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

How to retrive id(number- and also there is no key to read that num) and email

```
firebase.database().ref('/article/' + num + '/email/').on('value',function(snapshot) {
 var email = snapshot.val().email
  // ...
});
```

More information in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write